# Renaming all the files in folders within directory

Tags: python

Basically I have got it all done. But when actually trying to rename the files I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 

    "C:\Users\CHOMAN\Desktop\Earthquake_1_combine_3_jan\Earthquake_1_combine\wav\sort_inner_wav.py", line 21, in <module>
        os.rename(file, new_name)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Audio Track-10.wav' -> 'choman_10.wav'
```

Up until the last print statement the values are correct. Not sure how to rename it. ***Under wav folder there are 32 sub folder which has around 10 .wav files in it.***

```
import os

rootdir = r'C:\Users\CHOMAN\Desktop\Earthquake_1_combine_3_jan\Earthquake_1_combine\wav'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:

        filepath = subdir+os.sep+file
        if filepath.endswith('.wav'):

            f_name, f_ext=(os.path.splitext(file))

            if len(f_name) == 11:
              f_name = f_name+'-0'

            f_title,f_num =f_name.split('-')
            f_num=f_num.zfill(2)

            new_name = '{}_{}{}'.format('choman',f_num,f_ext)
            print (file, new_name)
            os.rename(file, new_name)
```

Comment: Does rename need the full path?

Comment: Yes that's what's confusing me. basically there are 32 folders under wav and in each folders there are around 10 .wav files. I am not sure what is the path that I have to give now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is:

```
os.rename(filepath, subdir+os.sep+new_name)
```

That's because you need the full path.

Comment: I would recommend `os.path.join` when combining paths: `os.path.join(subdir, new_name)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running this script under the same location as 'rootdir' and there are sub directories, you need to specify the absolute path of source file and destination file. Otherwise, the file would not be found.

```
# python 2.7
os.rename(filepath, os.path.join(subdir, new_name))

# python >= 3.3
os.rename(file, new_name, subdir, subdir)
```